# Trying to determine the name of a filter set up

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid-filtration

I am having an issue with caking in a process.  I am already trying to figure out ways to prevent the caking in the first place but I need a short term solution that will allow the line to continue running.

My idea is to take two filters and have them piped to run in parallel with one another.  However, I want a valve on the inlet of each individual filter.  I want this so while in production I can have Valve A open (allowing fluid through Filter A) while keeping Valve B closed (no fluid through Filter B).  Then when Filter A's mesh becomes clogged open Valve B, close Valve A, and remove and clean Filter A.  This way the fluid is still being constantly filtered and we do not have to stop the line for a filter change.

I am struggling with a name for this arrangement of filters as in my mind its a simple enough set up that a commercial version should already exist (I could be wrong about that).  All I am able to find on line are filter arrangements that allow series or parallel flow but not the ability to turn off flow to individual filters.  It could also be an option while ordering that maybe I am not catching.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I think you want to use the word "duplex" to describe the in line parallel assembly. But I think you still need to specify individual valves to the change flow path. (Edit: Previous comment was wrong, so I deleted it.)

Comment: I wonder if this is common enough to even warrant a name or systems that are pre-built.  It seems like the type of setup that would be fairly easy to make yourself.  I'd personally call it like a "redundant parallel filtration" system, but that doesn't really convey the isolation part of it.  I think a problem might be that often if the filtration is redundant there are other processes that are redundant with it, so they probably run more than just filters in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the kind of thing you are looking for.

http://m.eaton.com/mobile/ProductsandSolutions/Filtration/ManualPipelineStrainers/DuplexBasketStrainers/Model505-8inch/index.htm

They are common in fuel systems where you need to be able to clean one strainer while maintaining flow. You could build your own system using any sort of bypass valve and piping. Install a Y or T in your pipe and a valve on both legs, install your method of filtration then a second valve after the filter / strainer. to isolate that section for cleaning.

You didn't mention the fluid or contaminant you are removing nor the rate of flow so I don't know exactly what you need.